# How to install folder packages to local venv from another local venv

Tags: python, package, python-venv, anaconda3, libs

I have an anaconda env with a set of packages. I also have an python project which has an empty venv with python and pip. I need to install some packages from conda's env into an empty project. For example numpy.

But in conda env numpy is a folder with .py files, not a tar.gz archive.

I tried using —no-index —find-links:

C:\empty_proj\Scripts\python -m pip install —no-index —find-links=file:C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/ numpy

but it was throwing errors:

Looking in links: file:///C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy

Answer (score 0):

The Anaconda is caching it's packages in  `C:\Users\username\Anaconda{2,3}\pkgs` directory. You can the package from there. Just check your python version and required package version (from package name ) eg. numpy-1.20.3-py39hdbf815f_1.tar.bz2 require python 3.9.